# Window header sizing: total load on header

Tags: structural-engineering

I have a flat roof (dead load = 20 psf, live load = 30 psf) spanning 11 feet with a 2 ft. overhang. I'm trying to calculate the total load in plf on the header marked as X. 
[image: building profile]

Is this calculation correct:
TL = (DL + LL) × (11/2 + 2)
= (20 + 30) × 7.5
= 375 plf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not correct.

If you just want to calculate the load on the header with service loads and no load factors, you find the load on the header by getting the moments about an arbitrary point.

In this case the easy choice is the point at the left end of the rafters. let's denote it A and the point right on top of the wall with the header B.

$$ \Sigma M_{A}=0 \quad M_{A} = w*l*l/2 -R_{B}*11\ ft=0 \\ (20+30)*(11+2)*13/2 =R_{B}*11  $$

$$ R_{B}= 4225\ lbs/11 = 384,09\ lbs.ft $$

So each lineal foot of the header is supporting 384.09 lbs.

Comment: So if I use manufacturer software to size the header, which asks for the tributary width, I'll have to divide by the total load to give 384.09/50 = 7.68 ft.? (which makes me think that the software is probably using tributary width to calculate the plf, so perhaps 5.5+2=7.5 can be safely used as an approximation for the tributary width?)

Comment: In my comment above instead of "can be safely used" I should say "can be commonly used"

Comment: @coderoo, something like that. Their set up is for a simple rafter span, it seems. But 7.67 ft tributary span is ok.